# How to filter DateFrameGroupBy object by datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one column data with a datetime index. I'm able to group my dataframe by year and month using

```
grouped = data.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month])
```

I would like to know how to extract a subgroup containing values from a particular month for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the data for a particular month, you could do:

```
data[data.index.month == 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

month and year are attributes of a DatetimeIndex, so you can do:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])
```

It sounds like you could be after a [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.resample('M')  # default how='mean'
```

You can group by month (and year) more concisely using TimeGrouper (IIRC this is how resamples are done internally):

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))
```

*You'll have to wait 'til pandas 0.14 to combine this with other columns.*

Comment: Time series are indeed powerful in pandas. Thanks.